When does Manhattan distance become preferrable over Euclidean distance?
Say you're finding the optimal route on a plane.
With enough edges, is it easier/faster to use the manhattan distance instead of the euclidean distance? (For calculating the route)

Manhattan distance (or some multiple thereof) is sometimes a safe heuristic for the purposes of A* search, even when the desired distance is in Euclidean space.

You take whatever better represents the actual distance. Euclidean distance Works well in the Sahara, Manhattan distance is better in New York unless you have a helicopter.
The problem is NP complete and finding shortest distances will take exponential time. Manhattan distance will find the shortest distance faster if you have many places on the same street. (Think why that would be the case).
